# Trying to install phabricator on ubuntu ec2 instance, always redirects to default index page

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, phabricator

I'm trying to install Phabricator on an AWS web instance, but I'm having trouble configuring apache to get anything other than the Apache2 Ubuntu default page to show up.

I create

```
<Directory "/home/ubuntu/phabricator/phabricator/webroot">
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  # Change this to the domain which points to your host.                                                                                                                                                    
  ServerName -##-##-###-###.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

  # Change this to the path where you put 'phabricator' when you checked it                                                                                                                                 
  # out from GitHub when following the Installation Guide.                                                                                                                                                  
  #                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  # Make sure you include "/webroot" at the end!                                                                                                                                                            
  DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/phabricator/phabricator/webroot

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/rsrc/(.*)     -                       [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico   -                       [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-available

I then run

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite phabricator.conf
service apache2 reload
```

But when I load `http://ec2-##-##-###-###.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/` the default apache configuration page still shows up.  How comes its not disabled?

Comment: Have you tried removing the defaults from /sites-enabled  ??